# Display Hand string blackjack

Tags: c#, console-application

Hello I am currently trying to complete an assignment but I am having difficulty completing one of the classes, the class is called `hand.cs` and it looks as follows.

- [`Hand.cs`](http://pastebin.com/JEySJFLd)
- [`Twentyone.cs`](http://pastebin.com/RKURYiFH)
- [`Card.cs`](http://pastebin.com/jipvRf3c)

The other two sources of data that hand.cs is pulling from are called `card.cs` and `twentyOne.cs`, before people comment I know that this is an obvious solution and might seem laughable to many of the readers, however I have been looking at this hand.cs for better half of 4 days with no progress.

Any and all help regarding the `"public void DisplayHand(bool shortFormat, bool displaySuit)"` would be greatly appreciated, if it is not too much trouble with your answer can you outline the code to complete the return and give some feedback as to how it works.

Comment: it should display a hand of cards per player, 1 for an actual player and another set for the computer. It should display as "player has" two cards (two, five), then next line would be "dealer has" (ace, ten). all data is displayed as plain text with out much formatting

Comment: Current Console Output
http://i.imgur.com/qqfgI.png

Current Area That I am having trouble in
http://i.imgur.com/Zk9A3.png

Console Should look like this
After game selection.
Player has Seven, Nine.  

Dealer has Ace, Three.  
Player hit (H) or stand (S): H.
Player has Seven, Nine, Four.
Player hit or stand (S): S.
Player has 20 points.
Dealer hit.
Dealer has Ace, Three, Three, Six.
Dealer has gone bust (23 points) - you win.
You have won 1 games and I have won 0 games.
Another Game? (Y or N).

Answer (score 1):

In your `Hand` class, you're storing the current hand's cards in a `List<string>` suitably named `cards`. In your `DisplayHand` method you can iterate through the list with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (Card card in cards) {
    // process and/or display current card
}
```

Now, in your `Card` class, the `ToString()` method has been overloaded to accept two parameters:

```
public string ToString(bool shortFormat, bool displaySuit)
```

These same-two parameters are being conveniently passed to your `DisplayHand` function in the `Cards` class. Since you want to call the `ToString()` method *from* the `DisplayHand` method, you can simply pass in the arguments you received you'll be returned a nice & formatted string representing the card! You should, without much work, be able to combine the loop above with a call to the card's `ToString()` to get your required output:

```
public void DisplayHand(bool shortFormat, bool displaySuit) {
    StringBuilder cardOutput = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Card card in cards) {
        if (cardOutput.Length > 0) {
            // we already have one or more cards to display for this hand; separate them
            // with a space-delimiter
            cardOutput.Append(" ");
        }
        // add the current card to the display
        cardOutput.Append(card.ToString(shortFormat, displaySuit));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(cardOutput.ToString());
}
```

I'm using a single space as the delimiter between cards; you can update that to whatever you see fit. Also, if you don't want each list of cards to appear on a newline, just change the `Console.WriteLine()` to `Console.Write()` instead.

* Note: I chose to use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) in my example instead of basic string-concatenation for two reasons. The first is because in C#, strings are immutable (and concatenating them is far-less efficient than using `StringBuilder`); the second is to show you how to use `StringBuilder` (I only assume you don't use it as none of your sample code includes it). To do it without `StringBuilder` (with comments/etc removed):

```
string cardOutput = string.Empty;
foreach (Card card in cards) {
    if (!cardOutput.Equals(string.Empty)) cardOutput += " ";
    cardOutput += card.ToString(shortFormat, displaySuit);
}
Console.WriteLine(cardOutput);
```

Comment: I see, I have not come across "stringbuilder" before, that is a completely new concept. How much larger would the code be if it did not use stringbuilder?

Comment: The code wouldn't be any larger, it is just bad-practice to use string-concatenation in C# because strings are immutable (i.e. - they cannot be modified; every time you do `str = str + "addon";`, it creates a completely new string). I'll add an example of doing it without too.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the feedback and information you have provided it was incredibly insightful. when I think about it the way you have laid it out it all makes sense. Thank you once again